# What is the term for a time period less than a month?

Tags: word-request

I am working on a project that includes things that recurs at various time periods, but they are all less than a month, so some can be weekly, fortnightly or daily. I want an umbrella term for these types of things. The term can be in Latin or Greek.

The most I could come up with is oligomen or paucimens.

Comment: Do you know a suitable umbrella term in any other language?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta No. I was hoping there was one in Latin/Greek.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta submonthly is an English word apparently